# Relationship between ordinals and rank of well founded relations on $\mathbb N$

Tags: set-theory, infinity, ordinals

I want to understand the relation between ordinals and well founded relations on $\mathbb N$. I found a nice starting point here [cut-the-knot/ordinals](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/WhatIs/Infinity/Ordinals.shtml).

*Ordinals* start like this 0={}, 1={0}, 2={0,1}, 3={0,1,2}, ..., $\omega$={0,1,2,3,...}, $\omega+1$={0,1,2,3, ..., {$\omega$}}, ..., $2\omega$={0,1,2,3,...,{$\omega$},{$\omega+1$},...} and $\beta < \alpha$ iff $\beta \in \alpha$.

The *rank* of a well founded relation $\langle \mathbb N, <_\alpha \rangle$ is the least ordinal $\alpha$ for which you have an order preserving map $\alpha \to \mathbb N_{<_\alpha}$ that embeds all ordinals strictly less than $\alpha$ into the countable set.

---

**Here I define some well orderings with specific ranks**

We easily define well founded relations of rank $n \in \mathbb N$ by e.g. $a <_7 b$ iff $a < b$ and $a,b < 7$.

The normal relation $\langle \mathbb N, < \rangle$ has rank $\omega$, but we will call it $<_\omega$ later.

There is an easy bijection (hilbert hotel) between $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N \cup \{\infty\}$ and the well founded relation $n <_\infty m$ iff $n < m$ or $m=\infty$ and $n \not = \infty$ has rank $\omega + 1$.

To define a well order with rank $2 \omega$ we can split $\mathbb N$ into two copies, even and odd - then define an order relation that odd numbers are always smaller than even numbers to get. Similarly we define well founded relations of rank $n \omega$.

Using Cantor pairing, the lexicographic order on $\mathbb N^2$ has rank $\omega^2$, similarly we get well founded relations $<_{\omega^n}$ of rank $\omega^n$.

To define an order of rank $\omega^\omega$ I did this

$$(n,a) <_{\omega^\omega} (m,b) :\!\!\!\iff \begin{cases} n <_\omega m \\ n = m \land a <_{\omega^n} b \end{cases}$$

I think it's correct because you can embed ordinals of size $\omega^n$ into it for any $n$.

---

**Questions**

> How can I produce an explicit well ordering with rank $\omega^{(\omega^\omega)}$? (and other finite towers)

I thought we need to build a well ordering that can hold $\omega$, $\omega^2$, $\omega^3$, ..., $\omega^{\omega}$, $\omega^{2 \omega}$, $\omega^{3 \omega}$, ... $\omega^{\omega^2}$, $\omega^{\omega^3}$, $\omega^{\omega^4}$, ...
so I should build $\omega^{\omega^2}$ first but I don't know how to do that either.

Comment: There is an error in the second paragraph: $2 \cdot \omega = \text{"}\omega\text{ copies of }2\text{"} = \omega \neq \omega \cdot 2$.

Comment: I write multiplication backwards. is that ok?

Comment: If you _explicitly mention_ that you write products backwards it will be _less_ of a problem.  But all-in-all it is better to follow the notational standard.

Comment: The answer to the last question is "all ordinals less than the Chrurch-Kleene ordinal $\omega_1^\text{CK}$" and this would still be true if you replaced "decidable" with "hyperarithmetical."

Comment: This question is relevant, it brings up linear order exponentiation, which ordinal exponentiation is a special case of: https://mathoverflow.net/q/358455